# JAVA local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

I'm trying to return the `stats` object.

But I'm getting

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or
>   effectively final

on `stats = statistics;` How can I return the object but make sure `.close();` is run?

```
 public static Statistics getStatistics(String environmentName) {
    Container container = getContainer(environmentName);
    Statistics stats = new Statistics();

    try {
        dockerClient().statsCmd(container.getId()).exec(new ResultCallback<Statistics>() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(Closeable closeable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Statistics statistics) {
                stats = statistics;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {

            }
        }).close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stats;
}
```

Comment: [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). [idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: A local inner class has access to fields of the class enclosing it as well as the fields of the block that it is defined within. These classes, however, can access the variables or parameters of the block that encloses it only if they are declared as final or are effectively final.

Comment: @Brijesh what does it mean in simple english?

Comment: If I put `Statistics` says I cannot assign value to final...

Comment: Statistics stats = new Statistics() ; here stats is effectively final for inner class and you are trying to assign something. You can't assign to final after declaration.

Comment: Look, My code says it needs to be final. If I put final I cant assign value, so I cant return. Can you explain me how to do this?

Comment: @sadas According to https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/command/AsyncDockerCmd.java it looks like the `exec()` method is returning something, most likely the object you passed as an argument. Create a normal class of that type which stores the result in a field. Later, you can access the field from the returned object of the `exec()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an anonimous inner class:

```
new ResultCallback<Statistics>() { @Override public void onStart(Closeable closeable) { } @Override public void onNext(Statistics statistics) { stats = statistics; } @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) { } @Override public void onComplete() { } @Override public void close() throws IOException { } }).close();
```

The problem is that you're defining the stats in the method which is unnecessary because you're defining it again in the anonymous inner class `@Override public void onNext(Statistics statistics) { stats = statistics; }`

Instead, try to declare the variable directly in the class and initialize in null. Inside function only redefine it in the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `getStatistics` and immediately use the resulting stats. This is called *synchrone* usage.

But in effect one can only *asynchroneously* being informed by the callback that the statistics are finally arrived.

So change:

```
f(String env) {
    Statistics stats = getStatistics(env);
    g(stats);
}
```

to

```
f(String env) {
    retrievStatistics(env);
}

public static void retrieveStatistics(String environmentName) {
    Container container = getContainer(environmentName);
    stats = null;
    try {
        dockerClient().statsCmd(container.getId()).exec(new ResultCallback<Statistics>() {
            Statistics stats;

            @Override
            public void onNext(Statistics statistics) {
                g(statistics);
                stats = statistics; // Alternative when using onComplete instead.
            }

            @Override public void onStart(Closeable closeable) {}
            @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) { }
            @Override public void onComplete() {
                g(stats); // Or this
            }
            @Override public void close() throws IOException { }
        }).close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A busy wait loop as you did, is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture (java 8).
In this case:

```
public static Statistics getStatistics(String environmentName) {
    Container container = null;
    CompletableFuture<Statistics> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    try {
        dockerClient().statsCmd(container.getId()).exec(new ResultCallback<Statistics>() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(Closeable closeable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Statistics statistics) {
                if (!future.isDone()) {
                    future.complete(statistics);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                future.completeExceptionally(throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                if (!future.isDone()) {
                    future.complete(null);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {

            }
        }).close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // wait until statistics resolved
        return future.get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the exec code is synchronous, you can use AtomicReference, for example, as a temporal container. The approach will be similar to CompletableFuture example above, but with less overhead